# Subscription modelling in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to model the following scenario in Flask SQLAlchemy:

There are a list of `SubscriptionPacks` available for purchase. When a particular `User` buys a `SubscriptionPack` they start an instance of that `Subscription`.

The model is as follows:

[image: ERD]

A `User` can have many `Subscriptions` (only one of which will be Active at a time) and each `Subscription` will be referencing one `SubscriptionPack`.

How would this be modelled in SQLAlchemy?

Currently I have the `User.id` and `SubscriptionPack.id` referenced as `db.ForeignKey` in the `Subscriptions` model. And I have `Subscriptions` referenced as a `db.Relationship` in the `Users` table. This seems inconsistent and wrong and is leading me to have to hand-code a lot of SQL statements to return the right results.

Any help as to how to do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who stumble upon this, what I was looking for was the [bidirectional SQLAlchemy Association Object pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html).

This allows the intermediate table of a Many-to-Many to have it's own stored details. In my instance above the `Subscription` table needed to be an Association Object (has it's own class).